# How copy and rename files found in "find" function Linux?

Tags: shell, find, rename

I have a folder named `/home/user/temps` which has 487 folders.
In each folder I have a file called thumb.png.

I want to copy  all files named thumb.png to a separate folder and rename them based on the folder they came from.

Comment: rename them, how? If you replace the directory delimiter with something - let's say underline (_), you may get collisions with files, which already contain an underline. That's true for every valid character, and beside / and \0, which are forbidden in filenames, there is no safe harbor - any character might produce a collision.

Comment: Do folders have subfolders, or just a plain, wide folderstructure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for file in /home/user/temps/*/thumb.png; do new_file=${file/temps/new_folder}; cp "$file" "${new_file/\/thumb/}"; done;
```

**edit:**

the canonical wisdom, by the way, is that using `find` for this is a bad idea -- simply using shell expansion is much more reliable.  Also, this assumes `bash`, but I figure that's a safe assumption :)

**edit 2:**

for clarity, I'll break it down:

```
# shell-expansion to loop specified files
for file in /home/user/temps/*/thumb.png; do

    # replace 'temps' with 'new_folder' in the path
    # '/home/temps/abc/thumb.png' becomes '/home/new_folder/abc/thumb.png'
    new_file=${file/temps/new_folder};

    # drop '/thumb' from the path
    # '/home/new_folder/abc/thumb.png' becomes '/home/new_folder/abc.png'
    cp "$file" "${new_file/\/thumb/}";
done;
```

details on the `${var/Pattern/Replacement}` construct can be found [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#EXPREPL1).

the quotes in the `cp` line are important to handle spaces and newlines etc. in filenames.

Comment: new_file=new_folder? What's the purpose of the backslash in front of the slash in `new_file/\/thumb`?

Comment: @user: `${VARIABLE/PATTTERN/REPLACEMENT}` produces the value of `VARIABLE` but with the pattern replaces by the replacement text. Here the pattern is `/thumb` (the `/` needs to be escaped so that it doesn't look like `${new_file//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}`, which makes it a global replacement instead of a first-occurrence replacement) and the replacement text is empty.

Comment: Of course, now I see it. :)

Comment: You're assuming that the 487 directories are directly under `/home/user/temps`, which is not clear from the question. If they aren't, you need [find](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11697/how-copy-and-rename-files-found-in-find-function-linux/11709#11709) or `**`.

Comment: @Gilles -- I am indeed, that's how I read the question.  Appreciate the point, though :)

Answer (score 7):

This solution "flattens" the files in sub- and subsubdirectories so they all sit in one big directory. The new file name reflects the original path. For example `temps/dir/subdir/thumb.png` will become `newdir/temps_dir_subdir_thumb.png`.

```
find temps/ -name "thumb.png" |
  while IFS= read -r f do
    cp -v "$f" "newdir/${f//\//_}"
  done
```

The directories `temps` and `newdir` must exists. And you must execute the command from the parent directory of `temps` and `newdir`.

The command can also be done in one line

```
find temps/ -name "thumb.png" | while IFS= read -r f; do cp -v "$f" "newdir/${f//\//_}"; done
```

note the semicolons (`;`) where the newlines used to be.

---

example output

```
$ find temps/ -name "thumb.png" | while IFS= read -r f; do cp -v "$f" "newdir/${f//\//_}"; done
`temps/thumb.png' -> `newdir/temps_thumb.png'
`temps/dir3/thumb.png' -> `newdir/temps_dir3_thumb.png'
`temps/dir3/dir31/thumb.png' -> `newdir/temps_dir3_dir31_thumb.png'
`temps/dir3/dir32/thumb.png' -> `newdir/temps_dir3_dir32_thumb.png'
`temps/dir1/thumb.png' -> `newdir/temps_dir1_thumb.png'
`temps/dir2/thumb.png' -> `newdir/temps_dir2_thumb.png'
`temps/dir2/dir21/thumb.png' -> `newdir/temps_dir2_dir21_thumb.png'
```

If you are unsure then prepend `echo` to `cp` to see what is going to be executed.

```
find  temps/ -name "thumb.png" | while IFS= read -r f; do echo cp -v "$f" "newdir/${f//\//_}"; done
```

---

explanation

This works using [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): `${f//\//_}`. It takes the content of the variable `f` (which contains the filename with path) and replaces every occurence of `/` with `_`.

Note that this is a dumb text search and replace. If two distinct files end up with the same name one of the files will be overwriten.

For example two files `temps/dir/thumb.png` and `temps/dir_thumb.png`. Both files will be renamed to `temps_dir_thumb.png`. So one file will be lost. Which file will be lost is dependent on the order of how `find` found them on disk.

Obligatory pedantic warning: if your filenames contain newlines this command will break horribly.

Comment: Fails on files which contain a newline in their name.

Comment: Well that worked very well . one thing more , i have few zip files in some sub directories as well . is it possible to extract imgae from there as well . remember 'zip not tar'

Answer (score 2):

You can find, copy, and rename files in oneliner command with **-exec sh**:

```
find /home/user/temps -name thumb.png \
-exec sh -c 'cp "{}" "$(basename "$(dirname "{}")")_$(basename "{}")"' \;
```

*(The extra `"` are meant to deal with copying files with spaces).*

**Option 2** - with `xargs` (it can print each command before it is executed):

```
find /home/user/temps -name thumb.png \
| xargs -I {} --verbose sh -c 'cp "{}" "$(basename "$(dirname "{}")")_$(basename "{}")"'
```

> sh -c cp "temps/thumb.png" "$(basename "$(dirname "temps/thumb.png")")_$(basename "temps/thumb.png")"
>
> sh -c cp "temps/dir one/thumb.png" "$(basename "$(dirname "temps/dir one/thumb.png")")_$(basename "temps/dir one/thumb.png")"
>
> sh -c cp "temps/dir two/thumb.png" "$(basename "$(dirname "temps/dir two/thumb.png")")_$(basename "temps/dir two/thumb.png")"

Answer (score 1):

Short helper code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# echo cp "$1" ../tmp/"${1//\//_}" 
#
mv "$1" ../tmp/"${1//\//_}"
```

let's name it 'deslash.sh' and make it executable. Call it with:

```
find -type f -name thumb.png -exec ./deslash.sh {} ";"
```

It will fail, if a collision exists

```
a/b/thumb.png # and 
a_b/thumb.png
```

but that's unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mkdir /home/user/thumbs
targDir=/home/user/thumbs

cd /home/user/temps

find . -type d | 
 while IFS="" read -r dir ; do
   if [[ -f "${dir}"/thumb.png ]] ; then
     echo mv -i "${dir}/thumb.png" "${targDir}/${dir}_thumb.png"
   fi
done
```

**Edit**

I have added quoting in case any of your dir names have white-space chars embedded in them.

Also I have changed this so it will **only** print out the commands to be executed.
Examine the output of the script to be sure all files/path names look proper.
When you're sure there are no issues with the commands that will be executed, remove the `echo`.

Comment: I have some png files in some more subfolders , will that work

Comment: for my "A A"-folder, it produces: `mv -i ./A A/thumb.png ../tmp/.png` - all files end in ../tmp/.png  (../tmp is my target dir).

Comment: Add quotes and curly braces around all variables in above code, i.e. "${dir}"

Comment: @Mirror51 wrote : " files in some more subfolders , will that work ". Yes it should. Did you know you can execute each step of this script separately (or when piped together, each set of pipes). You can execute just the `find -type d` and see the output. Does that get all the directories you expect? It should, if not, please add some output to show the problem. Good Luck.

Comment: Won't work. `read dir` performs word splitting, and takes, from a directory `a\nb` a and b as two instances, which no masking can solve.

Comment: @userunknown : do I read you right? `a\nb` = newLine in dirName? Yes it is possible, but this is not a sysadmin-script we're writing here. Yes users do dumb things. Hopefully @Mirror51 is using normally formed directory names. BUT your point is well taken about word splitting and I am adding IFS="" to eliminate word splitting. Thanks for the feedback and cordially yours!

Comment: Well, things getting worse. `../thumbs.sh: line 4: while: command not found
../thumbs.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
../thumbs.sh: line 5: `do'
`. A consequence of IFS? Did you test your script? There are more and more tools which generate filenames without interaction, for example from saved webpages, the title is translated to a filename, and so on. That's how linefeeds happen to get part of filenames. AFAIK, my solution from above avoids the problems - you're invited to criticize it.

Comment: @userunknown : 1. are you the OP, @Mirror51? 2. I was mistaken with `IFS="" while read`, it should be `while IFS="" read`. 3. I don't have an easy way to test this. 4. newLines in filenames (I admit, while allowed), are IHMO pathological cases. But I guess we have to deal with it ;-). 5. no issues with your solution. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score -1):

To copy you need the command **cp**, and to rename for linux is the same than moving the file, so you have to do it with **mv** command. In Linux you always have to specify the whole path, from the source, if you are in another folder, and to the destination folder, of course. I'd be something like this, for copy:

```
cp /source_path/file /destination_path/
```

or to rename or move

```
mv /source_path/old_file /destination_path/new_name_file
```

Comment: This is only a minor part of the poster's question. Now explain how to iterate over the directories and copy the thumbnails :-)

Comment: the OP wants to use `find`

Comment: Yes, you're right... I don't know what happened to me...