# How can I find files and then use xargs to move them?

Tags: find, rename, xargs

I want to find some files and then move them.

I can find the file with:

```
$ find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -name x*
```

I tried to move them to my `~/play` directory with:

```
$ find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -name x* | xargs mv ~/play/
```

but that didn't work.  Obviously mv needs two arguments.
Not sure if (or how) to reference the xargs 'current item' in the mv command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find pattern and move](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84318/find-pattern-and-move)

Comment: Pass `sh -c` to the `-exec` or to `xargs`. Here's an example how to find-copy-rename files in one-liner command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/623157/43233

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Look at Stephane's answer for the best method, take a look at my answer for reasons not to use the more obvious solutions (and reasons why they are not the most efficient).

You can use the `-I` option of `xargs`:

```
find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -name "x*" | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' ~/play/
```

Which works in a similar mechanism to `find` and `{}`. I would also quote your `-name` argument (because a file starting with `x` in the present directory would be file-globed and passed as an argument to find - which will not give the expected behavior!).

However, as pointed out by manatwork, as detailed in the `xargs` man page:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
          names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted  blanks  do  not
          terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline
          character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

The important thing to note is that `-L 1` means that only one *line* of output from `find` will be processed at a time. This means that's syntactically the same as:

```
find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -name "x*" -exec mv '{}' ~/play/
```

(which executes a single `mv` operation for *each* file).

Even using the GNU `-0` xargs argument and the `find -print0` argument causes exactly the same behavior of `-I` - this is to `clone()` a process for each file `mv`:

```
find . -name "x*" -print0 | strace xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' /tmp/other

.
.
read(0, "./foobar1/xorgslsala11\0./foobar1"..., 4096) = 870
mmap(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =     0x7fbb82fad000
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26066, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26066, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fbb82fa6000
close(3)                                = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,         child_tidptr=0x7fbb835af9d0) = 661
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 661
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,         child_tidptr=0x7fbb835af9d0) = 662
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 662
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
.
.
.
```

Comment: That assumes file names don't contain newline, single quote, double quote or backslash characters.

Answer (score 25):

Perhaps this command is possible now and wasn't back in 2013, but this works perfectly for me:

```
ls pattern* | xargs mv -t DESTINATION/
```

The `-t` key puts the destination folder first, freeing up `mv` command to have all last arguments as just the files to be moved.

Comment: this was the simplest solution that worked for me

Comment: But that fails if any of the files that match `pattern*` is of type directory, or the names contain whitespace or single quote, double quote, or backslash characters. You'll notice that I gave a *correct* answer using `mv -t` already in 2013.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: mv: illegal option -- t

Answer (score 20):

With GNU tools:

```
find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -name 'x*' -print0 |
  xargs -r0 mv -t ~/play/
```

The `-t` (`--target`) option is GNU specific. `-print0`, `-r`, `-0`, while non-standard and originating in GNU are also found in some other implementations like on some BSDs.

POSIXly:

```
find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -name 'x*' -exec sh -c '
  exec mv "$@" ~/play/' sh {} +
```

Both run as few `mv` commands as necessary and work whatever characters the file names may contain. The GNU one may have the advantage that `find` keeps looking for files while `mv` starts moving the first batch.

Beware that all the files and directories will end up in one directory, beware of clashes if several files in different directories have the same name.

Comment: This solution is much better performing, since it calls `mv` once for all arguments (or for all of `-L` or `-n`, if supplied). Otherwise, calling `mv` for each file will get old (and slow) fast.

Comment: I recommend using the `-n` flag

Answer (score 4):

I would also like to suggest some alternate tools. Of course `find` has been around for a very long time so it is a robust tool but I found `fd` to be a lot easier to work with:

```
fd -d1 -epdf -S+2m -x mv {} books/
```

This command would move all 2MB+ pdf files in the current directory to a subfolder called 'books'.

I like `fd` because it complains a lot less where other tools like `find+xargs` have more edge cases you need more knowledge to be aware of. For example if the file has a single quote in the name then xargs will have potentially unexpected behavior.

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Comment: To nitpick, doesn't answer the question since xargs isn't used.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with below command and tested and its worked fine

```
find /tmp/ -ctime -1 -type f -name "x*" -exec mv -t ~/play/ {} \;
```

Comment: No point using the GNU-specific `mv -t` if you're using `\;` instead of `+`.