# Make xargs pass as first parameter

Tags: xargs

I'm trying to produce this behaviour:

```
grep 192.168.1 *.txt
```

By passing a string into grep via Xargs but it is going on the end instead of as the first parameter.

```
echo 192.168.1 | xargs grep  *.txt
```

I need to tell xargs (or something similar) to put the incoming string between 'grep' and '*' instead of on the end.

How do I do this?

Comment: Similar to [How can I find files and then use xargs to move them?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90886/how-can-i-find-files-and-then-use-xargs-to-move-them).

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
$ echo 192.168.1. | xargs -I{} grep {} *.txt
```

#### Example

Sample files:

```
$ cat {1..3}.txt
192.168.1
192.168.1
192.168.1
```

Example run:

```
# example uses {} but you can use whatever, such as -I{} or -Ifoo
$ echo 192.168.1. | xargs -I{} grep {} *.txt
1.txt:192.168.1.
2.txt:192.168.1.
3.txt:192.168.1.
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why? What are you replacing with -I ? I don't get it.

Comment: It seems the curly brackets are a place holder. You can replace {} with anything you like: echo 192.168.1. | xargs -I pholder grep pholder *.txt

Comment: @denormalizer I am not sure why, but using `{}` as place holder is not working for me, instead, `%` works for me.

Comment: @zyy Would be interesting to know what OS you are running. I think I've got it working on Ubuntu and CentOS

Comment: @denormalizer I think mine is CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 | xargs -0 grep 192.168.1
```

This will not overflow the shell's command line length with too many file names. To avoid confusing `xargs`/`grep` with file names that have spaces, `-print0` and `-0` options will delineate each found name with a null rather than a LF.