# Find all files in all subdirectories with name ExampleDir

Tags: centos, find, filenames, xargs

I want to find all files in all subdirectories which has a name `ExampleDir`

eg.

```
+ ParentDirA
   + ChildDirA
     - file1.txt
   + ExampleDir
     - file2.txt
+ ParentDirB
   + ChildDirB
     - file3.csv
   + ExampleDir
     - file4.csv
```

Executing command should return: file2.txt and file4.csv

I have tried the following:

```
find . -type d -name "ExampleDir" | xargs find -type f
find . -type d -name "ExampleDir" -exec find -type f {} \;
find . -type d -name "ExampleDir" -exec find -type f {} +
```

They all return:

```
find: paths must precede expression
```

If I were to go down this route (which I think is logical) I would have to find out how to pipe the path to the find command.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider simplifying things with [GNU find's `-path`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html#Full-Name-Patterns) extension:

```
find . -type f -path "*/ExampleDir/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer over at: 
[Make xargs pass as first parameter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91596/make-xargs-pass-as-first-parameter)

```
find . -type d -name "ExampleDir" | xargs -I {}  find {} -type f
```