# find and remove files bigger than a specific size and type

Tags: find

I want to clean up my server from large log files and backups.

I came up with this:

```
find ./ -size +1M | xargs rm
```

But I do not want to include mp3 and mp4. I just want to do this for log and archive files (zip, tar, etc.)

How will the command look like?

Comment: try `find / -type f \( -name "*zip" -o -name "*tar" -o -name "*gz" \) -delete` .. add whatever extension you want to delete

Comment: and better to dry run the command without the `-delete` portion for sanity check

Comment: @Saeid Yazdani. ..... Deleting all +1M in / will "delete" your OS : `libc.so.**` is about 1.8MB ! -

Comment: @KnudLarsen you are right I meant to be in my home directory and fo "find ./"....I edited the question

Comment: @spasic thanks, it was what I needed...you want to post as answer?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
find -type f \( -name "*zip" -o -name "*tar" -o -name "*gz" \) -size +1M -delete
```

- the `\( \)` construct allows to group different filename patterns
- by using `-delete` option, we can avoid piping and troubles with `xargs` See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24954/when-is-xargs-needed) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90886/how-can-i-find-files-and-then-use-xargs-to-move-them)
- `./` or `.` is optional when using `find` command for current directory

**Edit:** As Eric Renouf notes, if your version of `find` doesn't support the `-delete` option, use the `-exec` option

`find -type f \( -name "*zip" -o -name "*tar" -o -name "*gz" \) -size +1M -exec rm {} +`

where all the files filtered by `find` command is passed to `rm` command

Comment: It's worth noting that not all versions of `find` support `-delete`, though you could still avoid `xargs` with `-exec rm {} +`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to exclude files by name, you can use this syntax:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.mp3' ! -name '*.mp4' -size +1M -delete
```

or if your `find` does not support `delete`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.mp3' ! -name '*.mp4' -size +1M -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: It's worth noting (here too) that not all versions of `find` support `-delete`

Comment: By the way which do not? I checked vanilla OSX and `gfind`...

Comment: Well, I don't have AIX to check directly myself, but it's not documented in the options for that version: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm

Answer (score 4):

Based on the above answers I used below command to clear the server from big log files (after cd'ing into /var/lib/jenkins)

```
find -type f -name *log -size +500M -delete
```

Comment: For those wondering how to run this command without limiting to a certain filename pattern( like "log"),  just do

$ find -type f -iname "*" -size +100M -delete

Comment: It almost never makes sense to say ``-name "*"`` (and ``-iname "*"`` even less so). To process *all* files, just leave out the `-name` directive, as in the command in the question.